# Is there a way to export an sql view as an executable file

Tags: sql-server

I made a view in a software database to permit my clients to fast edit data of a software very poor on gui, i want to access and edit this viewed data without opening mssql server management studio every time,how can i make a fast executable file that opens that view and permits to edit and save data ?

Comment: Why would you use SSMS to begin with? This is an administration tool Why not use eg Excel or any other application to read the data? As for the question itself it doesn't make much sense. A view is essentially a query definition, not the results it would return when it runs. Yes, you can export the data. You can use SSMS itself to export data in a lot of formats and destinations including Excel, MS Access, CSV etc from the `Export Data` menu

Comment: is there a way to access this view from excel and live edit the data ? i've made the connection but i can only read

Comment: That depends....is this an updateable view?

Comment: If you want to update the data you will have to write some code in VBA that will update the data when it changes. I don't know of anyway you can databind it with automatic updates back to the server.

Comment: It's an updateable view on mssql but it seems that in excel it's read-only, is there a way to execute from scratch an executable coded to display that view in an editable windows